# with Maven installed package, how to resolve dependency in profile?

Tags: maven, installation, profile

I have a project with module A that will be build with or without profile say -Pnewlib to build with different version of library let's say by default use libjar-1.0 and when -Pnewlib will use libjar-2.0.

Then, I have a module B to depends on module A. The issue is that how can I get the right dependency in module B for libjar? I want to assemble a fat jar so I need to figure out which version of libjar to include.

In my test, it seems to me that when mvn -Pnewlib install module A, though it will build with libjar-2.0. but the installed pom do not reflect this. Thus when module B resolve the dependency, it will resolve the dependency as libjar-1.0. This is wrong, How can B resolve the right dependency in this case through A?

(I don't want to have module B know anything about the libjar-1.0 and libjar-2.0. it should handle by module A, and module B just simply call into module A.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: err.., just say, A depends on either libjar1.0 or libjar2.0 with different profile, B depends on A, then how can it find out correct libjar dependency.

Comment: If I am not describing it clear enough , I just found a question which essentially, is the same issue as mine. stackoverflow.com/q/20060909/3047806